# When do we expect sitecore.stackexchange.com to come out of public beta and goes fully public?

Tags: support, public-beta

When do we expect sitecore.stackexchange.com to come out of public beta and goes fully public? We are at around 1300 users and 1200 questions. It says that it remains in public beta till it builds up a critical mass of users, questions, and participation.

So what should be the numbers?

Comment: A note for posterity: [Sitecore.SE left beta in December 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/335251).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many factors that come into play. I think, first and foremost, we need more of a userbase with higher reputation scores. Enough so that we can hold a proper moderator election.

[image]

While there is no clearly defined metric, I'd say we need at least 500 users on 200+ rep, with 25 or so users on 2.000+.

But it doesn't come down to metrics and numbers. This has been stated a number of times. The site needs to be thriving, bringing in good content. So that's where the focus should be :-)