# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2022

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Sitecore Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **August 22, 2022**, as your “graduation” election as a result of having lost your beta label a while back.

The timeline:

- On August 15, 2022, we'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on August 22, 2022, users can [nominate themselves](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/election/2). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On August 29, 2022, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, we'll simply check with the current moderation team on whether anyone is planning on stepping down, and appoint the candidates who've nominated (and aren't already pro-tem mods) and we'll default to considering this a "pro-tem election" just to try to bring the total number of moderators on the site up to 3 (for full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)). (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If there is an election, we'll announce the results on meta on September 6, 2022 (or September 13, 2022, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please include them in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to take the responsibility. Please consider me as a candidate.

Comment: As [the election page](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/election/2) notes, users are required to have at least 300 reputation points to be able to nominate in the election.